# Reverse XY coordinates from csv to qgis?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gps, coordinates, xy

I find it very difficult to import GPS data from CSV to QGIS and finally I have discovered that the first column in CSV table was Y coordinate and the 2nd was X coordinate.

In the picture you can see the settings for the file import

To check the real position in google maps I have to insert (first value, second value) so I believe that was the same in QGIS

[image: XY_fields]

Why is this happening? Is it regular?

Comment: I don't know if it is regular or not. Just thought you would find this interesting. [Lat Long or Long Lat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636564/lat-long-or-long-lat).

Comment: Yes, it is regular that if coordinates have names X and Y there are two interpretations about which one stands for latitude/northing and which one for longitude/easting. You can start reading from http://www.ogcnetwork.net/axisorder.